# Failed to enable constraints (in SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
   nume, SUM(cantitate) AS Expr1
FROM 
   bon_produse
WHERE
   (bonid = @p1)
GROUP BY 
   nume
```

I get the error from title and I cannot figure it out how it is wrong...

> *Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.*

Comment: Seems like there are some records in bon_produse table which have foreign keys defined, but parent rows have been deleted! Check for the constraints applied on bon_produse table!

Comment: Seems like you have a primary or unique key defined in the DataTable, but not updating it.

Comment: The *data table* used to store the results of this query is the source of this error. Check the *constraints* defined on nume and Expr1 columns.